# Error in graphql in Express , node js

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, express-graphql

I'm trying to run graphql server in express. But it throws following error.

```
var graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql'); // express graphql
var { buildSchema } = require('graphql');  // graphql
var schema=buildSchema(
    type Query {
        name:String});

var classifyRoot={
     name:()=>{
        classified.find({name:"shoes"},function(err,classified){
            //res.render("card",{classifieds:classifieds});
            return classified.name;
        });
    },};
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  schema: schema,
  rootValue: classifyRoot,
  graphiql: true,
}));
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more of the code, there's nothing to work with from just the error

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, please find updated code

Comment: So which line is the error on? It is almost definitely just a typo somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument for `buildSchema` should be string. (Notice the [back-ticks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals))

```
var schema=buildSchema(`
    type Query {
        name:String
    }
`);
```

Answer (score -1):

Its missing the `=` !

To use types you need to do this:

```
type Query = {
  //Variables and types goes here:
  //ex:  username: string
}
```

Hope i have helped

Comment: This is actually untrue, if you just take a look at the GraphQL docs http://graphql.org/learn/schema/